# javascript. is it posible for one member of an object to access another member of that object without explicit reference to the object itself?

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods, closures

For example:

```
var myObj={

  myValue="hola",

  asMember=function(){ alert( this.myValue ); }

};


myObj.asMember(); // will work fine

var asGlobal=myObj.asMember; // global alias for that member function
asGlobal(); // won't work in javascript (will work in AS3, but i need js now)
```

So the question is, can I rewrite `asMember` so that it could be called by global alias and without mentioning `myObj` at all? It's understood that if I define it:

```
asMember=function(){ alert( myObj.myValue ); }
```

it will work, but in my case, mentioning `myObj` is not acceptable even inside the function itself (because `myObj` may be reassigned later, but `asGlobal` won't change and should keep working)

Answer (score 1):

To invoke your `asGlobal`, you would need to do:

```
asGlobal.call(myObj);
```

[ECMAScript 5](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) will introduce the `bind()` method for enforcing the context of a function. This would allow you to do the following:

```
var asGlobal = myObj.asMember.bind(myObj);
asGlobal();
```

However `bind()` is not yet supported in current browsers, as far as I know. In the meantime, you may want to check out [Prototype's bind](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) implementation, which is virtually identical to the ECMAScript 5 method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var asGlobal = function(){myObj.asMember();}
```

If myObj changes to a different object, the function will use the latest value.  If you don't want this, try:

```
var asGlobal = function(o){return function(){o.asMember();}}(myObj);
```

Comment: nono. `asGlobal` MUST be just an alias for `asMethod`. The only thing I am allowed to do is change `asMethod` so that it somehow knows that it is a member of `myObj`

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha!
Closures do well

```
function myObj(){

  var myValue="hola";

  return{
    asMember:function(){ alert( myValue ); },
    anotherMemer:function(){/* ... */}
  }

};

var temp=myObj();

var asGlobal=temp.asMember; // global alias for that member function
asGlobal();
```