# JavaScript function pass-through?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm not sure if this is doable, but I would like to be able to set a jQuery UI event as a function (directly), as opposed to continuing to wrap in additional `function(event, ui) { ... }` wrappers.

Hopefully you can see what I'm going for from the example below.

Here is what I would like:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "somepage.php",
    select: dropdownSelect,
    minLength: 0
});
```

Now I would think that the above would work, since I'm simply trying to say "continue firing this event, just over to that function".
Unfortunately, that will not work, and I'm ending up with this: (and for some reason, a disconnect from all data)

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "somepage.php",
    select: function(event, ui) { dropdownSelect(event, ui) },
    minLength: 0
});
```

Comment: I can guarantee you that there is no difference in those two examples you have given.

Comment: @Sean: After trying to get a few things (like getting the over-wrapped functions going), I have gotten it to work. I don't know why it wasn't working before (as that was **many** revisions ago. There has to be some difference, though because now the wrapped version loses `$(this)`.

Comment: You may want to check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656469/assigning-document-getelementbyid-to-another-function/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662851/javascript-is-it-posible-for-one-member-of-an-object-to-access-another-member-of) regarding that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two examples should both work in theory:

```
var dropdownSelect = function(event, ui) {  
    // Code to select drop down
};

$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "somepage.php",
    select: dropdownSelect,
    minLength: 0
});
```

And this:

```
function dropdownSelect(event, ui) {  
    // Code to select drop down
};

$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "somepage.php",
    select: function(event, ui) { dropdownSelect(event, ui) },
    minLength: 0
});
```

JavaScript functions are first class citizens, which means that you can treat them like any other object.

Comment: Not so, the first example is a self executing `FunctionExpression` which will result in an error due to a full stack.

Answer (score 0):

sure why not define that function first:

```
var dropdownSelect = function(event, ui) { dropdownSelect(event, ui) };
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "somepage.php",
    select: dropdownSelect,
    minLength: 0
});
```

Comment: Aside from  declaring a separate variable and wrapping my function (that takes the same parameters), that's what I have, and it is not passing through. I guess the the additional layer there is the difference? So no matter what I have to add the wrapper?

Comment: Will crash the browser due to infinite loop.

Comment: This is going to cause a stack exception as `dropdownSelect` is a `FunctionExpression` that calls itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropdownSelect = function(event, ui) { ... };
var onDropdownSelect = function(event, ui) { dropdownSelect(event, ui) };
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "somepage.php",
    select: onDropdownSelect,
    minLength: 0
});
```